# Visual Studio Code doesn't see path to aliases

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vite, tsconfig

When trying to go to **import** in **VSCode**, it gives an error: **Could not open the editor because the file was not found**.

I use **Vite**. I specified **alias** in the settings and also specified it in **tsconfig**, but this did not help.

The build/development process works correctly, but I can't switch between files where the alias is used.

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import {
  defineConfig,
  loadEnv
} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

const {
  NODE_ENV
} = process.env;
const nameDevelopment: string = 'development';
const isDev = NODE_ENV === nameDevelopment;

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
      // generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:5]',
      generateScopedName: isDev ? '[local]__[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
      // generateScopedName: "prefix-[name]-[hash]",
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: true,
    host: true,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: function({
          name
        }) {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/img/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/\.css$/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/css/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/fonts/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }
          // default value
          // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
          return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // Функция которая поможет решить проблему путей
  experimental: {
    renderBuiltUrl: function(filename: string, {
      hostId,
      hostType,
      type
    }: {
      hostId: string,
      hostType: 'js' | 'css' | 'html',
      type: 'public' | 'asset'
    }) {
      // console.log(arguments);
      if (type === 'asset') {
        if (hostType === 'css') {
          const stringRemove = 'assets';
          const stringLength = stringRemove.length;
          const stringPresence = filename.indexOf(stringRemove);
          if (-1 !== stringPresence) {
            console.log('..' + filename.substring(stringLength));
            return '..' + filename.substring(stringLength);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // Custom setting
    // "baseUrl": "src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@styles": ["src/*"],
    },
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your aliases are in vite.config.ts and tsconfig.json is different. You need to bring them to the same view. The working view is specified in vite.config.ts

That is, instead of this

```
"paths": {
  "@styles": ["src/*"],
},
```

You need to write this

```
"paths": {
  "@styles/*": ["src/assets/styles/*"],
},
```

In this case, not only the assembly will work, but also the path substitution mechanism in VSCode.